# Is is possible for the FormClosed event to fire more than once

Tags: c#, winforms

As opposed to the `FormClosing` event, which can be fired multiple times in a slow-to-respond app with a user jumping on the close button repeatedly.

Is it possible for the `FormClosed` event to fire multiple times?

Eg, is the following `try/catch` necessary?

```
private void MyForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    // Dispose the CancellationTokenSource
    // Is it possible for this to be fire more than once!?
    try
    {
        cts.Dispose();
        cts = null;
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Comment: FormClosing can only fire more than once when you have a bug in the code.  It is a nasty kind of bug that makes this website's name relevant.  Never, *never* hide exceptions that tell you that you have such a bug.

Comment: Form closing fires every time a user clicks the close button.  If you have running tasks that need co-operative cancellation then you need to give feedback to the user, via the form that the tasks are cancelling, meantime they continue to bang on the Close button.  One way to solve this is to hide the close button after the first time they hit the button, but there are plenty of other ways to ignore successive close requests while waiting for co-operative cancellation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `cts.Dispose();` by itself would be absolutely fine, setting it to `null` is redundant and doesn't help the garbage collector, and try catch is *overkill*.

A `CancellationTokenSource.Dispose` just takes care of a *timer* and a *handle* to a *kernel event* (`ManualResetEvent`), both are cleaned up in a thread safe manner and both implementation will handle being called twice and are fault tolerant.

Depending on how you instantiated the `CancellationTokenSource` you could also use the *null conditional operator* for good measure.

**Example**

```
private void MyForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
  => cts?.Dispose();
```

It's worth noting `CancellationTokenSource` checks if it has been previously disposed anyway.

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
   if (disposing && !_disposed)
   {
      ...
```

As to whether a *Form* `OnClose` event can be called twice, I haven't deviled into the code, yet my assumption is that it will work on the message pump, and unless you call the event yourself it will only be called once. Even if otherwise, you are covered anyway

Comment: Thanks - re the CTS Dispose - Documentation for `CancelationTokenSource` states that `all references must be released after calling Dispose()`.  I have come across several places which say to set it to null after disposing of it... am I, and others,  mis-interpreting this `references must be released` requirement?

Comment: @RowanSmith Dispose is releasing the resources which is potentially a timer and a kernel event. The null has no power here and does nothing in this situation

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is always possible to add the same event multiple times to the same handler, in which case it would be called multiple times!

But outside of, this I can't find any documentation which guarantees that it will only be called once, but looking at the WInform lifecycle https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/order-of-events-in-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

I would say that you can be pretty sure that it should be only called once.

However, I would still employ safe coding practices and keep the try catch, or use the null conditional operator.

If you don't catch an exception which, such as this, is harmless, and/or have (or later add) a global exception handler then it will catch and handle such things which could be totally unnecessary and clog up your logs files with what is effectively junk. (I have seen this too often)